# Client - Server Button request

Tags: asp.net

Sorry. This may be very simple for you...

I have a Button in my Web Form. In the Browser, I opened the Fire Bug and saw the following HTML corresponding to the Button

```
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Upload" name="btn">
```

Following is my Button HTML at server side...

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="ButtonClick" />
```

So When the user hits the button, which is right now at the client side, invokes the Server side handler of the button.

My Question is how is this mapping being done internally, I meant, user is hitting the button at client side and this is executing the code at server side? Because button is no more available at server. Page is downloaded and now it is at Client side. right?

In windows Form application, this is very simple to understand this concept as the Button Event and handler are both lying in the same file and there is no Client-Server concept.

Comment: I agree with this answer of @Joel Etherton. The answer is valid when using ASP.NET WebForms (thats the case). The answer of AMember is partialy valid only when developing with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is bound up in the page's ViewState, which is passed as an argument during the PostBack. So in effect, the button continues to "live" and various arguments are passed along with it. If you look at the source of your generated page, you'll see a `__doPostBack` JavaScript call which handles the actual event that is occurring. This is sent in the form of an http POST request, and the ViewState provides any "stateful" information to the page's server-side code.

There is a lot more going on here, and I recommend you research the [Asp.Net Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to understand it more thoroughly.

Comment: I looked at the source of generated page. Not showing the `__doPostBack JavaScript call`. My server HTML is this `<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="ButtonClick" /> `

Comment: Is your source code in a separate file or is it included as script?

Comment: **Everything is bound up in the page's ViewState, which is passed as an argument during the PostBack** Can you tell us which function is being called that accept the argument of `ViewState` ?

Comment: @testing: It isn't bound in a function, it's available as a global property called `ViewState` much the same as you would use `Request.Form`. The button itself and any specific arguments regarding the button would be what is passed into `__doPostBack`, which should be there somewhere. It may not be immediately visible but it should be there right after the `<body>` tag along with the hidden fields for other .Net helpers.

Comment: It's not available at my end. **[Please check this screenshot of View Source](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bwGJD.png)**

Comment: Ah, this is because you've selected a file input field, and that has changed the form's post submission method. The ViewState is still there, but the JavaScript call will no longer be a viable submission method, so there will be a different method .Net will be using to track the events.

Comment: It's idle. I did not use it. I can remove this line of code from HTML.

Comment: can you show any other documentation/Video/discussion in this context ?

Answer (score 0):

The button click invokes a form submission that posts the values to your server, that in turn fires the button click event.